# UILocalNotification actions and snoozing

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

I'm working on a custom app for a client and am still relatively new to iOS development. The app involves setting reminders and I'm using UILocalNotifications. Now from my research the action on the notification will always run the app but I'm really hoping someone can correct me on that. Also from what I've read you are limited to the 'View' or 'Close' options. Ideally I'd love to have 3 buttons on the notification and not have to open the app to perform an action.

I'd like a 'dismiss' option, 'snooze' option, and an 'ok' option that dismisses the notification but runs some code in the background.

I came across a notification related question where somebody suggested opening the app with a modal view and presenting the options from there. Possible, just not as clean, I guess.

Any other ideas or is this what I have to do to achieve my desired functionality? If that's the case is there a way to close the app after I've selected one of my options from the modal view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible, as the notification is not created by your app but by the system, so you can't customize the appearance of the notification. (also in iOS 5, the user can choose to display the notifications as banners instead of alerts, which would hide any other button than the view and close button, if that were to be possible).

Secondly there is no way to close your app, as iOS is a user centric system, where the user takes the decision on whether to open or close app, and not the app itself.

Comment: I get what you're saying but it would be the user making the decision, they would tap a button which performs a function and then either closes or sends the app to the background. So the only way to close the app is by pressing the 'Home' button?

Comment: Yes, the only way to close an app is to press the Home button

Comment: not really ... you can close your app at anytime by calling "    exit(0);". I have seen it on App Store on password protected apps (bank).